# Ranking subcategories while keeping order of ID

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following table:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | cat1 | cat2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | A    | foo  |
|  2 | A    | foo  |
|  3 | A    | bar  |
|  4 | B    | sci  |
|  5 | B    | ble  |
|  6 | B    | ble  |
+----+------+------+
```

I would like to rank the subcategory (cat2).

Desired outcome:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | cat1 | cat2 | res  |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | foo  |    1 |
|  2 | A    | foo  |    1 |
|  3 | A    | bar  |    2 |
|  4 | B    | sci  |    1 |
|  5 | B    | ble  |    2 |
|  6 | B    | ble  |    2 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

I use DENSE_RANK with PARTITION BY to get the following result:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | cat1 | cat2 | res  |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | foo  |    2 |
|  2 | A    | foo  |    2 |
|  3 | A    | bar  |    1 |
|  4 | B    | sci  |    2 |
|  5 | B    | ble  |    1 |
|  6 | B    | ble  |    1 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Statement:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cat1 ORDER BY cat2 asc) as res, t.* 
  FROM mytable t 
 ORDER BY id;
```

As you can see, the only thing I'm missing is the order of the result. Currently, the rank is based on the alphabetic order of cat2. However, I want to preserve the order given by the id's (see desired outcome). Simply changing the ORDER BY of my DENSE_RANK will not do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT MIN(id) id, cat1, cat2
              FROM test
              GROUP BY cat1, cat2 )
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.cat1,
       t1.cat2,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.cat1 ORDER BY t2.id asc) as res
FROM test t1 
JOIN cte t2 USING (cat1, cat2)
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb0ccb4ac70cdd4c64c64c9e9cf3e0a5)

Of course, CTE may be converted to subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`LAG() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY ..)` and `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY ..)`

analytic functions combination :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT LAG(cat2,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cat1 ORDER BY id) lg,
       t.* 
  FROM mytable t 
 ORDER BY id
)
SELECT id, cat1, cat2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN lg=cat2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY cat1 ORDER BY id) as res
  FROM t2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=88be3fd6d84eea3b0103dc6806887dea)</kbd>

Comment: Add record `(7,'B','sci')` - its `res` will be `3`, whereas it was previously assumed to be `1` for this `cat2` in this `cat1` group.

Comment: Well, but how do you percieve that what OP don't want to have this while he says *I want to preserve the order given by the **id*** @Akina e.g. he probably means `res` will increase as `cat2` change along `id` increases.

Comment: OP says: *I would like to rank the subcategory (cat2).* Rank means that the same values have the same rank. Regardless of the order.

Comment: *the rank is based on the alphabetic order of **cat2**. **However**, I want to preserve the order given by the **id*** @Akina